# RabbitMQ: Auto-clean \ Deleting queues after consuming message

Tags: rabbitmq, queue

My application would need to connect to a RabbitMQ queue and consume the message in it (only 1) . And I must also make sure that the queue is deleted right after the message is consumed. I was looking for a way to do this, with simple configurations. Is that possible? If yes, how?

I was thinking of the following options:

*setting exclusive to true:*

I believe this would mean auto-delete is also set as true (unless set specifically as false). And the queue would get deleted when the 'last consumer is cancelled'. But what does this actually imply? Does this mean it will get deleted once the messages are consumed? Also does this mean that it can be only consumed using the connection which declared the queue?

*setting the expiration parameter to x seconds:*

This would be a cleaner way to destroy the queue I believe. But the problem here is finding the right value. The message from the queue can be consumed in 3 seconds - but also can so happen that it takes up to a minute or more. In this case, it would remain until the expiration seconds - even if the queue is consumed much earlier.

*Are there better alternatives?*

Answer (score 0):

I used google to search `site:rabbitmq.com queue delete` and the second hit is this document:

https://www.rabbitmq.com/queues.html

In that document, the "Temporary Queues" section states the following:

> An auto-delete queue will be deleted when its last consumer is cancelled (e.g. using the basic.cancel in AMQP 0-9-1) or gone (closed channel or connection, or lost TCP connection with the server).

This sounds exactly like what you need. Once your consumer reads and acknowledges the single message, it can disconnect and RabbitMQ will delete the queue.

An exclusive queue (also documented on that page) will only allow access from a single connection, so if your publisher is different from your consumer (which it sounds like) that won't be an option.

Comment: I get your point. But in this case, we would need to explicitly cancel the connection I believe. Is there a way that the queue is deleted as soon as it is consumed ? (without having to cancel \ delete the queue) . I believe expires also works the same, the only difference being it will remain until the specified time of expiry

Comment: Please follow up here - I am assuming you cross-posted to the mailing list - https://groups.google.com/d/topic/rabbitmq-users/PDxRvNNYx9A/discussion